# How to fix: GitLab pipeline - failed to start

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

**Introduction:** I am new to creating GitLab pipelines.

**Details:**

- The type of executor I am using for Runner is; Shell.
  (I am not sure if this can be used or new runner needs to be registered with a different executor.)
- Gitlab-runner 13.11.0

On trying to execute the below code which I have written in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, it throws the error.

```
image: "ruby:2.6"
 
test:
  script:
  - sudo apt-get update -qy
  - sudo apt-get -y install unzip zip
  - gem install cucumber
  - gem install rspec-expectations
  ##TODO grep on all folders searching for .feature files
  - find . -name "*.feature"
```

The error I am receiving is as follows.

Outout from Gitlab pipeline execution:

[image: preview]

Can I request you to please help me fix this and run this successfully?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are running on a Windows shell runner. The commands you have written are for Linux. Options are to either update your `script` to work with Windows, use a `Linux` environment, and/or use a docker runner over a shell runner.

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion. I switched from Gitlab runner with shell executor to Docker executor and it started working